# After redirect to login page, show Toaster message

Tags: reactjs, redux

how to display this toster message after reloading the page in React js.

```
const store = configureStore();
let isLogout = false;
const handleResponse = (response) => {
    if (response && response.data && response.data.status && response.data.status.code === 551 && !isLogout ) {
        isLogout = true;
        store.dispatch(actions.logout()).then(() => {
            window.location.reload(); 
            handleErrorMessageToastr("Authentication Fail")
        });
    }
    return response
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want this toster show after logout.
Basically, if any service returns a 551 then i have to redirect login page and also to show user friendly message.

Comment: what I would recommend is to pass a prop in the login page component. And in the login component check if the prop is true then display the toast. Or you can show toast first and then redirect.

Comment: If i show toast first then it is showing for few millisecond.